# Play audio from firebase storage android studio java

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I have a couple of audios in my firebase storage. I also have a firebase database where I have documents. Document incorporates several fields such as: name, surname, audio. How can I start playing audio via the link which is provided in the field "audio", if the name is "abc"?

Comment: Have you tried to use [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer)? Or [ExoPlayer](https://exoplayer.dev/)?

Comment: I have, the thing is that I have a link with an audio which I need to play. How can put this link and play the audio?

Comment: Add the URL to one of the linked resources. I suggest you try implementing ExoPlayer, for example.